# Parse findInBackground does not work

Tags: android, parse-platform

The find on the db does not complete, so the FindCallback.done() method is never called, no errors, nothing, just is not called. this is the code

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category").setLimit(1);
    pq.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {



        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();

        }



    });
```

I can see the prints before and after this portion of code, but the exception is never thrown. Please, I do really need help.

Edit: I use the parse-login before this point and it works correctly, even the saveInBackground() works correctly, the only problems I find are about queries, (find, getfirst ecc).

Comment: Any logcat output? Also, I would check `if(e!=null) e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: the find on the db never ends and so the done() method is never called! If you can take a look at the code you can see I throw a RuntimeException whatever is the value of e, this exception is never thrown!!!

Comment: Check that you have declared the Internet permission in your manifest file. Also, make sure the device has access to the Internet.

Comment: I already done what you said, I use the parse-login before this point and it works correctly, even the saveInBackground() works correctly, the only problems I find are about queries, (find, getfirst ecc). I'm editing the question to specify this

Comment: This code snippet does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved, I found out that the background features offered by Parse do not work if in your activity there are fragments, so you have to implement them yourself. The only strange fact is that in the beginning some function (such saveInBackground as I mentioned above) worked.

Comment: can you cite your sources ? I'm experiencing the same limitations of Parse using fragments and background features.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ACL column in the parse object row, maybe you don't have permission to read.Double click on the ACL column and check the "public Read".

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category").setLimit(1);

pq.findInBackground(new FindCallback< ParseObject >() {

@Override
public void done(List< ParseObject > parseObjects, ParseException e) {
        // Success
        } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: As I wrote up above, the done() method is never called, the find on the db does never end.

Answer (score 0):

The `pq.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()` is meant to return only one object, so you need to help it zero in on that object, for example a particular name or item. 
Try adding `pq.whereEqualTo("item", biscuit);`.

If you want to return a list of objects you need to use a different callback.
End product should look like this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category").setLimit(1);
pq.whereEqualTo("item_key_here", "item_value_here");
pq.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {



    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if(object != null){
     //do stuff here

    }



});
```

Comment: still we are unable to execute done functions on trying above